# How to calculate the amount of possibles sets of strings with elements of differents lenghts?

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization

I need to write  an algorithm that calculates the amount of possible strings given some restrictions:

```
The strings must have an N amount of characters;
The strings only have an X number of different letters;
The strings can't have an Y number of digraphs;
```

For example, for N = 2, X = 3 and Y = 6:

```
The string: _ _ _
My set of letters: {a, b, c}
Set of proibited digraphs: {aa, bb, cc, ab, ac, bc}
#The proper result is 1, but I'm getting -9
```

So far, my code only works properly when the string only have a lenght of 2. I'm being unsuccessful in making an equation that cover all cases. I can't make a bruteforce algorithm because the string lenght can have any value lower than 10^9

That's my code:

```
def  arrangements(sizeOfSet, numberOfElements, isDigraph):

  if isDigraph:
    return pow(numberOfElements, sizeOfSet - 1)
    #sizeOfSet is subtracted by 1 cause digraphs occupies 2 spaces

  return pow(numberOfElements, sizeOfSet)
```

And then I subtract the arrangements of my set of letters from the arrangements of the proibited digraphs set.

Comment: Can you show what the solution to your example would be?

Comment: Just added to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of a comment but it is too big for a comment.

Unfortunately I don't think you can solve this problem as an algorithm with `N`, `X` and `Y` as its input because that data is not enough. You need the actual set of digraphs rather than its size.

Consider two similar problems. Both have an alphabet of 2 letters (`a`, `b`) and `N = 3` but the sets of prohibited digraphs are different.

**Problem #1**

We prohibit `aa` and `ab`. So all the allowed triplets are:

- `baa`
- `bba`
- `bbb`

So there are 3 solutions

**Problem #2**

We prohibit `aa` and `bb`. So all the allowed triplets are:

- `aba`
- `bab`

There are only 2 solutions.

This happens because digraphs `aa` and `ab` interact differently than digraphs `aa` and `bb`. Particularly no triplet is filtered out by both `aa` and `bb` at the same time, but the triplet `aab` is filtered out by both `aa` and `ab` so effectively one less triplet is filtered out.

What I think could work is using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) over the length of the strings controlling which is the current last character.

---

**Update** (sketch of the algorithm)

Let's try to solve it as a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem over the length of the string. What we want to keep as the state is the number of strings ending with each character (so an array of size `X`, or a dictionary of the same size). If we find a way to update such a state for each next string size, then when we get to the `N` we can just sum values over the array and that will be our final answer.

Updating the state is easy. Let's consider what happens when we add a new character to a valid string of the length `n-1`. We get a new valid string of the length `n` unless the last pair is one of the prohibited digraphs. So building new state is easy (here is a Python-style pseudo-code):

```
for prev_last_char in chars:
    for new_last_char in chars:
        if (prev_last_char, new_last_char) not in prohibited: 
             new_state[new_last_char] += old_state[prev_last_char]
```

Obviously the initial state is array (or dictionary) full of `1` for every character.

Assuming `prohibited` access time is `O(1)` which should be achievable with a hash-based dictionary, the complexity of one step is `O(X*X)`. Thus total algorithm complexity is `O(X^2*N)`.

Comment: The problem can be solved, some people did it in C++. This is a challenge from URI, maybe I messed up with my explanation so here's the link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_2819_en.html

Comment: Also, I read about combinatorial analysis, and I think that arrangements are the path to solve that problem, but, as you said, the digraphs interaction is what is making hard to traduce in a equation :/

Comment: @EnzoFerrari, I didn't claim the problem can't be solved. I claim that it can't be solved substituting the set of the prohibited digraphs with its size. I see no reason why dynamic programming, that I suggested at the end of my answer, would not work.

Comment: I expect that DP solution has a complexity `O(X^2*N)` (i.e. `N` steps of `X^2` complexity) which might be good enough.

Comment: Yes, the time limit for python is 2 seconds. I don't have experiencr with dinamic programming, but I'll read about it. Thanks!

Comment: @EnzoFerrari, if you have no experience with DP at all, I'm going to update my answer with a sketch of an algorithm. It might take me about 10 minutes. Meanwhile read about [DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and try to solve it yourself.